# SMTPSenderRefused (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required)

Tags: python, django

I make a website with django and im having some troubles whit the reset password feature in deployment with heroku (works fine locally), when i try to use it, an error pops up:

`SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a68sm8842573qkd.10 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://mytobiapp.herokuapp.com/password-reset/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused
Exception Value:

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a68sm8842573qkd.10 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py in sendmail, line 867
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:

['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

***settings.py***

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("GMAIL")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("CONTRASEÑA_GMAIL")
```

I already tried to allow acces to less secure apps and use the displayunlockcaptcha feature of google, but nothing seems to work. Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't saved the environment variables properly.
To test out if your variables are working then try this in that directory.

```
import os
a = os.environ.get('variable_a')
b = os.environ.get('variable_b')
print(a, b)
```

it should give None if not set.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this exact error recently when promoting a Django site into production.

Add the following into `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'email@yourserver.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'email@yourserver.com'
```

As soon as I added those into `settings.py` this error vanished.

Reference: [Django deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/)

I would add that the above checklist is really worth reviewing. There are additional settings you should adjust in production, particularly concerning HTTPS.

Comment: This should be an email generated from your website host, right? like if you have www.example.com DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@example,com' ?